# can not set flash.geom.Matrix3D rawData

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d

consider the following code:

```
var t:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D(
    new Vector.<Number>([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,10,10,0,1])
);

trace(t.rawData[12]);
```

the trace command will print "0" for me, and it is visible with debugger that rawData contains an identity matrix actually. I simply can not set the values contained by Matrix3D!

I'm using flash 11.2.

Thanks, for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your syntax for creating a pre-filled Vector is wrong.

You should have:

```
new <Number>[values]
```

Instead of:

```
new Vector.<Number>([values])
```

Demo:

```
var wrong:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>([1,2,3]);
var right:Vector.<int> = new <int>[1,2,3];

trace(right[1]); // 2
trace(wrong[1]); // error
```

Comment: Tried the following:
var t : Matrix3D = new Matrix3D(new <Number>([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,10,10,0,1])); but it did not even compile with flex builder (IT WAS WRONG)